# What is benefit of using bastion (EC2) instance in kubernetes cluster (EKS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

What is benefit of using bastion (EC2) instance in kubernetes cluster (EKS) ?

Answer (score 2):

This access option improves the cluster security by preventing all internet access to the control plane. However, disabling access to the public endpoint prevents you from interacting with your cluster remotely, unless you add the IP address of your remote client as an authorized network.